# SSH Key mapping to a user

Tags: unix, ssh

I have a server, and three people access that server as user test with their SSH keys, their public keys is saved in authorized_keys file.

Is there a way to map a user to a ssh key.
For example if user with public key A1 log in to the server, then i can match the A1 key to a person name in a config file or a small table(created by me) and get the name of the active users.
How can i check what are the ssh keys used to log in to server, and are currently active, is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Do they really need to share one account? Can't you create an account for each of the three people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form the [manpage](http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys) we can read that you can set environment variables in the authorized_keys file for every key. For this to work you need to set

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart your ssh server.

Then add an `environment="name=value"` in front of the ssh public key in the `authorized_keys file`, like this for example:

```
environment="sshuser=user1" ssh-rsa AAAA...
```

If you then log in to the server you can access the env variable:

```
$ ssh server
$ echo $sshuser
user1
```

Hope it helps!